# Как передать значение инпута в new Data()?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция

```
setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('.submit').click();
    }, "время выполнения");
```

И есть инпут, в который пользователь введет время нажатие кнопки

```
<input type="time" id="time" class="time" step=".1">
```

Мне нужно рассчитать задержку setTimeout разностью new Date и значения инпута. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понял вопрос но думаю как-то так

```js
document.querySelector('.submit').addEventListener("click", submit);

function submit(e){
 console.log("click");
}

document.querySelector('.time').addEventListener("change", changed);

function changed(){
  
  var value = new Date(new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + document.querySelector('.time').value).getTime() - new Date().getTime();
  console.log(value);
  setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('.submit').click();
    }, Math.abs(value));
  
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="time" class="time" step=".1">

<input type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Send Request">
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, долго мучался с этим